# Optimising 2D rotation

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, avx

Given the classic formula for rotating a point in 2D space:

```
cv::Point pt[NPOINTS];
cv::Point rotated[NPOINTS];
float angle = WHATEVER;
float cosine = cos(angle);
float sine = sin(angle);

for (int i = 0; i < NPOINTS; i++)
{
    rotated[i].x = pt[i].x * cosine - pt[i].y * sine;
    rotated[i].y = pt[i].x * sine   + pt[i].y * cosine;
}
```

Given NPOINTS is 32 and the arrays are aligned, how would one go about optimising the code for SSE or AVX? Searching around here and elsewhere didn't turn up anything useful, and I got lost about here:

```
__m128i onePoint = _mm_set_epi32(pt[i].x, pt[i].y, pt[i].x, pt[i].y);
__m128 onefPoint = _m128_cvtepi32_ps(onePoint);
__m128 sinCos = _mm_set_ps(cosine, -sine, sine, cosine);
__m128 rotated = _mm_mul_ps(onefPoint, sinCos);
```

But how to go from `[y*cosine, -x*sine, x*sine, y*cosine]` to `[y*cosine + -x*sine, x*sine + y*cosine]`? Is this the best approach? Does it easily scale to `__m512`?

**UPDATE**: I did a little more research and I now have approximately:

```
__m128i onePoint = _mm_set_epi32(pt[i].x, pt[i].y, pt[i].x, pt[i].y);
__m128 onefPoint = _m128_cvtepi32_ps(onePoint);
__m128i twoPoint = _mm_set_epi32(pt[i+1].x, pt[i+1].y, pt[i+1].x, pt[i+1].y);
__m128 twofPoint = _m128_cvtepi32_ps(twoPoint);
__m128 sinCos = _mm_set_ps(cosine, -sine, sine, cosine);
__m128 rotated1 = _mm_mul_ps(onefPoint, sinCos);
__m128 rotated2 = _mm_mul_ps(twofPoint, sinCos);
__m128 added = _mm_hadd_ps(rotated1, rotated2);
__m128i intResult = _mm_cvtps_epi32(added);
int results[4];
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)results, intResult);
```

This gives a 50% speed-up from 11% of the processor time to about 6%. Expanding to `__m256` and doing four points at a time gives another speed-up. This looks quite awful code, but am I heading the right direction?

Comment: SIMD works better "vertically" rather than "horizontally" - try processing 4 points per iteration.

Comment: @PaulR has it right. If you process 4 points simultaneously not only will it be more efficient but the code algebraically will be almost identical to the scalar code i.e. it will be obvious how to write it with intrinsics.

Comment: For AVX you should process 8 points simultaneously (4 with SSE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of struct of arrays (AoSoA) and process eight points at a time.  In the code below `point8` is struct of arrays containing eight points. The function `rotate_point8` rotates eight points and has the same algebraic structure as the the function `rotate_point` which rotates a single point.  The function `rotate_all8` rotates 32 points using the AoSoA `point8*`.

The single point rotation code does 4 multiplications, one addition, and one subtraction.

If we look at [the assembly for `rotate_point8`](https://godbolt.org/g/EYXNN5) we see that GCC unrolled the loop and does 4 SIMD multiplications, one SIMD addition, and one SIMD subtraction per unroll. That's the best you can do: eight for the price of one.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct point8 {
  __m256 x;
  __m256 y;
};

struct point {
  float x;
  float y;
};

static point rotate_point(point p, float a, float b) {
  point r;
  r.x = p.x*a - p.y*b;
  r.y = p.x*b + p.y*a;
  return r;
}

static point8 rotate_point8(point8 p, float a, float b) {
  __m256 va = _mm256_set1_ps(a), vb = _mm256_set1_ps(b);
  point8 r;
  r.x = _mm256_sub_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(p.x,va), _mm256_mul_ps(p.y,vb));
  r.y = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(p.x,vb), _mm256_mul_ps(p.y,va));
  return r;
}

void rotate_all(point* points, point* r, float angle) {
  float a = cos(angle), b = sin(angle);
  for(int i=0; i<32; i++) r[i] = rotate_point(points[i], a, b);
}

void rotate_all8(point8* points, point8* r8, float angle) {
  float a = cos(angle), b = sin(angle);
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) r8[i] = rotate_point8(points[i], a, b);
}

int main(void) {
  float x[32], y[32];
  point p[32], r[32];
  point8 p8[4], r8[4];
  float angle = 3.14159f/4;

  for(int i=0; i<32; i++) y[i] = 1.0*i/31, x[i] = sqrt(1-y[i]*y[i]);
  for(int i=0; i<32; i++) p[i].x = x[i], p[i].y = y[i];
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) p8[i].x = _mm256_load_ps(&x[8*i]), p8[i].y = _mm256_load_ps(&y[8*i]); 

  for(int i=0; i<32; i++) printf("%f %f\n", p[i].x, p[i].y); puts("");

  rotate_all(p, r, angle);
  for(int i=0; i<32; i++) printf("%f %f\n", r[i].x, r[i].y); puts("");

  rotate_all8(p8, r8, angle);
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    _mm256_storeu_ps(x, r8[i].x), _mm256_storeu_ps(y, r8[i].y);
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++) printf("%f %f\n", x[j], y[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've now plugged this into my code, and I see a real 5% speed-up for the complete frame processing routine. There's a couple more optimisations I can make (preload `va` and `vb`, and calculate memory offset `y * width + x` in SSE) which will help a little further.

Comment: @KenY-N, 5% is not very big. Using a AoSoA can be a PITA I think especially if you only get a 5% gain. I would not be surprised though if you have other bottlenecks (e.g. memory bandwidth) which are masking the gain i.e. if you only timed the scalar and vector rotation you would see a much bigger speedup. But learning to use an AoSoA is useful I think. It's something you should think about from the start otherwise it requires a lot of cumbersome refactoring/rewriting.

Comment: Yes, there's a *lot* of other processing, but this was the hot-spot that appeared on my profiler. Timing just the code above did of course show a huge improvement.