# Rotate 2D points using System.Numerics.Vectors

Tags: c#, simd

I'm looking to optimize a program that is basing a lot of its calculations on the rotation of a lot of 2D Points. I've search around to see if it's possible to do these calculations using SIMD in C#.

I found a c++ answer here that seems to do what I want, but I can't seem to translate this into C# using the System.Numerics.Vectors package.

[Optimising 2D rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432251/optimising-2d-rotation)

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how this can be done?

The below code shows the regular method without SIMD. Where Point is a struct with doubles X and Y.

```
    public static Point[] RotatePoints(Point[] points, double cosAngle, double sinAngle)
    {
        var pointsLength = points.Length;
        var results = new Point[pointsLength];

        for (var i = 0; i < pointsLength; i++)
        {
            results[i].X = (points[i].X * cosAngle) - (points[i].Y * sinAngle);
            results[i].Y = (points[i].X * sinAngle) + (points[i].Y * cosAngle);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

**Edit:**
I've managed to get an implementation working using two Vector< float> but from benchmarking this, this seems to be a lot slower than the previous implementation.

```
    private static void RotatePoints(float[] x, float[] y, float cosAngle, float sinAngle)
    {
        var chunkSize = Vector<float>.Count;
        var resultX = new float[x.Length];
        var resultY = new float[x.Length];

        Vector<float> vectorChunk1;
        Vector<float> vectorChunk2;

        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i += chunkSize)
        {
            vectorChunk1 = new Vector<float>(x, i);
            vectorChunk2 = new Vector<float>(y, i);

            Vector.Subtract(Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk1, cosAngle), Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk2, sinAngle)).CopyTo(resultX, i);
            Vector.Add(Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk1, sinAngle), Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk2, cosAngle)).CopyTo(resultY, i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at using the `Vector2` and `Matrix3x2` classes, I believe the multiplication operations between them uses SIMD where possible

Comment: You can **not** do that using c# unfortunately! The example you showed uses intrinsics, basically assembly instruction using 128 bit xmm registers, which they work in c/c++. However you can create a dll(in c/c++) and call it from your c# code.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Thanks, I have look into the Vector2 possiblities, it even has a Transform method for this, using a Matrix3x2 rotation matrix. However, there seems to be a huge lack of examples online. So I can't figure out how to use this in combination with an array for Vector2's etc...

Comment: Working with an array of points is bad for SIMD. It can be done much more efficiently if you have one array containing all the X coordinates and an other array containing all the Y coordinates, like in the example you added in the edit.

Comment: @harold transformations are matrix multiplications which is easily accelerated with SIMD.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes but it only works out well for 4x4 matrixes, and then it still doesn't scale easily to AVX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code added in the edit is a good start, however the codegen for `Vector.Multiply(Vector<float>, float)` is extremely bad so this function should be avoided. It's an easy change to avoid it though, just broadcast outside the loop and multiply by a vector. I also added a more proper loop bound and "scalar epilog" in case the vector size does not neatly divide the size of the input arrays.

```
private static void RotatePoints(float[] x, float[] y, float cosAngle, float sinAngle)
{
    var chunkSize = Vector<float>.Count;
    var resultX = new float[x.Length];
    var resultY = new float[x.Length];

    Vector<float> vectorChunk1;
    Vector<float> vectorChunk2;
    Vector<float> vcosAngle = new Vector<float>(cosAngle);
    Vector<float> vsinAngle = new Vector<float>(sinAngle);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i + chunkSize - 1 < x.Length; i += chunkSize)
    {
        vectorChunk1 = new Vector<float>(x, i);
        vectorChunk2 = new Vector<float>(y, i);

        Vector.Subtract(Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk1, vcosAngle), Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk2, vsinAngle)).CopyTo(resultX, i);
        Vector.Add(Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk1, vsinAngle), Vector.Multiply(vectorChunk2, vcosAngle)).CopyTo(resultY, i);
    }
    for (; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        resultX[i] = x[i] * cosAngle - y[i] * sinAngle;
        resultY[i] = x[i] * sinAngle + y[i] * cosAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @harold. I tried to benchmark this code compared to the regular way of doing it without SIMD, the SIMD version seems to be about 10 times slower on my computer... The snippet I used to benchmark can be seen here. https://pastecode.xyz/view/d8c6d061
Any idea why?

Comment: If I turned of "Prefer 32bit" for the project I got the speedup I was looking for. It is now about 5 times faster than the other method.

Comment: @user978281 yes in 32bit mode `Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated` is false and vectors still work but only slowly/emulated

Comment: why the scalar epilog? why not just let the final smaller chunk do its thing normally?

Comment: @gzak there are no smaller chunks, the chunk size just has the size that it has, trying to load a vector near the end of the array is an error if there are not enough elements left until the end of the array. Doing an unaligned "vector epilog" that goes up to the end of the array and possibly overlaps a bit with the last full chunk is a known technique, but trickier, and requires that the arrays are at least as big as a chunk (otherwise that unaligned chunk would start at a negative index)